# I can't install any python package

Tags: python, json, pip, pycharm

When I'm trying to install any package using ***PyCharm*** terminal, I always get this error.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python>pip install PyMySQL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\Scripts\pip-script.py",
line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==19.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\setupt
ools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\setupt
ools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2793, in load_entry_point
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\setupt
ools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2411, in load
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\setupt
ools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2417, in resolve
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19
.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19
.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19
.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19
.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19
.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip\_internal\commands\completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19
.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "C:\Users\Mi\Desktop\MAIN\Coding\python\Coursera\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19
.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip\_internal\download.py", line 6, in <module>
    from json import json
ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'json' (C:\Users\Mi\Anaconda3\lib\json\__
init__.py)
```

But when I use `pip install` the library is installed, but it still doesn't work in ***PyCharm***.

Thanks for help! And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can try to download corresponding pacages in '.tar.gz' format on this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
- manually unzip it
- enter the unzipped folder
- install the package through the following cmd command:

```
python setup.py install
```

*here I suppose you are using windows and your python is above 3*

If you are continuously encontering this problem,I suggest you alter the original download channel to a mirror.

Comment: Ow, I already fixed it. My venv directory had the wrong path, but thank you anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the library through terminal and Pycharm still doesn't recognize the library, I think may be you should select the correct interpreter for the project by clicking the project interpreter at the bottom right in a Pycharm project. Look at the image in this
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWnFm.png). Click on the Interpreter which is named just "Python 3.x", it may work then.

["3.x" as in which version of python you are using]

Comment: Ow, I already fixed it. My venv directory had the wrong path, but thank you anyway)